# modeling a repeating event in a database, and using UILocalNotification to fire the event

Tags: ios, core-data, uilocalnotification

I'm not sure how this would work, but what I'd like is something similar to Apple's alarm clock that comes with the iPhone.  It basically just lets you pick a time of an alarm, name the alarm, and then you can choose how often you want it to repeat (Sunday - Saturday).  Based on what you choose, the alarm fires once, or at a repeated interval.

In my Core Data model, I wasn't sure how to model that.  If I were thinking in terms of just plain old objects, I would think I would have some alarm object, and one of its properties would be an array.  In that array I could have the day values of Sunday-Sautrday.  Then when a new alarm object is created, I would schedule a UILocalNotification for the time selected, and the days chosen.  To model that in terms of database objects, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.  I was thinking something like:

Alarm - (name/string)
Day - (Sunday - Saturday/represented by integers 0-6, 1 to many relationship from Alarm to Day)

Assuming that is ok in the database, then I'm not sure how I should go about scheduling the UILocalNotifications since I thought you could only have 64 per app.  I'm thinking that I could have some mechanism to schedule the first 64 alarms possible, then when the app is opened, it would just reschedule the next upcoming 64 events.  Is that how I would do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 2 entities is overkill. I would just have the `Alarm` entity and have a single integer attribute on it to hold the alarm days. Outside of the entity, I would have an enumeration which defines how the alarm days number is interpreted. Something like:

```
typedef AlarmDays {
    Monday           = 0,
    Tuesday          = 1 << 0,
    Wednesday        = 1 << 1,
    Thursday         = 1 << 2,
    Friday           = 1 << 3,
    Saturday         = 1 << 4,
    Sunday           = 1 << 5
} AlarmDays;
```

Then you can test which days it should be on using:

```
if (alarm.alarmDays & Monday) {
    // the alarm should fire on mondays
}
```

And you can use the features of `UILocalNotification`, such as `repeatInterval` so you don't need to explicitly add gazillions of notifications to the system.

Comment: I'm not too great with bitmasks.  I can see how this would work if the repeat was only one day.  But how does this work if it's supposed to repeat say Tuesday, Thursday, and Friday?  Thanks!

Comment: you set it up like that with `alarm.alarmDays = Tuesday | Thursday | Friday;` The test is as per the above, substituting instead of `Monday` (you only test for one day at a time really).